# How to redirect to calling application logout page instead of cas logout page

Tags: spring-boot, cas, jasperserver

I have connected 2 application (web application and jasper) through cas server. When i logout through web application or jasper I'm able to see the logout page of cas

Instead of this If user logout through web application user should be able to see web logout page instead of cas logout page and if user logout through jasper than user must be able to see japser logout page instead of cas logout page.

I have tried :
LogoutFilter logoutFilter=new LogoutFilter("https://cas_server_ip:8443/cas/logout?service=https://web_app_ip:8443/Webapp/logoutsuccesspage", securityContextLogoutHandler());

and enabled cas configuration:

cas.logout.followServiceRedirects=true

cas.logout.redirectParameter=service

Using this i was not able to redirect to success page of  calling application

Comment: Just make a request at `https://cas_server_ip:8443/cas/logout?service=https://web_app_ip:8443/Webapp/logoutsuccesspage`.

Comment: I tried using this but it didn't worked out for me

Comment: Have you tried a simple GET request at the aforementioned url and did not work? You should include more details on how you are making the logout requests. Your question is too broad.

Comment: /logoutsuccesspage is a GET method in web application. I'm able to see the https://casserverip:8443/csa/logout?service=https://web_app_ip:8443/Webapp/logoutsuccesspage  in browserurl